# Creating EJB 3.0 or 3.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I would be very much thankful to clear me some question about this new EJB3.0 and above version:

1) if suppose I need `ejbCreate`, `ejbActivate` and all other events so how can I get it from the new EJB3.0 and above ver.

2) I always have problem to find particular xml file to alocate a JNDI name according to variety of Application Servers so is there any way that I can give JNDI name without xml file and can also be use a portable name that in every Application Server it can be findable of EJB deployed on app server remotely

3)Can any buddy tell me, i have hosting plan of Java/Linux which supports
i) Tomcat - 5.5.xSupport
ii)JDK - 1.6.x Support
iii)JSP/servlet - 2.0 Support

can it be possible that EJB 3.1 be deployed because some where i have got that tomcat is not able to deploy EJB so please give me some advice help...

Thank You...!!!
please Help me...!!!

Comment: six years have passed since ejb 3.0 release, but it's still 'this new EJB 3.0'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `ejbCreate, ejbActivate` etc. are related to EJB 2.x, if you need similar functionality in EJB 3.x, you should decorate your methods with annotations `@PostActivate, @PrePassivate` etc. Method signature should follow [certain rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/ejb30/annotations.html#wp1416976), example for `@PostActivate`:

> The method annotated with @PostActivate must follow these
>   requirements:
>
> ```
> The return type of the method must be void.
> The method must not throw a checked exception.
> The method may be public, protected, package private or private.
> The method must not be static.
> The method must not be final.
> ```
>
> This annotation does not have any attributes.

2) It seems that you're referring to `name` and `mappedName` attributes of `@Stateless` and `@Stateful` annotations. For more details see [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateful.html). From my experience mappedName is better, but it's application-server-specific, e.g. on Glassfish it works perfectly. Example:

```
@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/myBean")
public class MyFirstBean {
..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1) if suppose i need ejbCreate, ejbActivate and all other events so
>   how can i get it from the new EJB3.0 and above ver.

In EJB 3 and above, the [EJB lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html) is handled through life cycle annotations, such as: [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [@PreDestroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html).

> 2) i always have problem to find perticular xml file to alocate a JNDI
>   name according to variety of Application Servers so is there any way
>   that i can give JNDI name without xml file and can also be use a
>   portable name that in every Application Server it can be findable of
>   EJB deployed on app server remotly

The [@Stateless](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) and [@Stateful](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateful.html) annotations have two attributes that might solve this issue (name and mappedName). Yet

> The mapped name is product-dependent and often installation-dependent.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered Question 3 ..

> 3)Can any buddy tell me, i have hosting plan of Java/Linux which supports i) Tomcat - >  5.5.xSupport ii)JDK - 1.6.x Support iii)JSP/servlet - 2.0 Support

No, you are going to need a server that supports Java EE.  Read [How to deploy EJB based application on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-3-or-web-application-on-tomcat)