# How to work with ejb entity bean - I must deploy ejb entity bean in ejb container

Tags: ejb, entity, javabeans

I want to know to work with EJB entity bean. I must deploy EJB entity bean in ejb container.

But I have seen some projects my friends working use java persistence api with EJB entity bean,
but they are deployed in servlet container instead of ejb container.

Answer (score 0):

OpenEJB should be integrated with tomcat (Nowadays, there is tomcat EJB compatible version, it is called tomEE)

See [How to deploy EJB based application on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-3-or-web-application-on-tomca)

Comment: Thanks in adavance jan.zanda