# Run an EJB in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, ejb

I have a running ejb in Jboss. 
Jboss Port: 8080. I can access it using an application which runs in JBOSS. 
JNDI Properties :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
```

I am trying to access the same ejb using a Tomcat application. My Tomcat server runs on the port 8180. I am using the same JNDI Properties.

But I am getting the following error while running it:

```
    Error : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name SayHelloBeanImpl is not bound in this Context
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name SayHelloBeanImpl is not bound in this Context
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at Hello.doGet(Hello.java:34)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Why it is so?

Comment: Your look up is not able to find the JNDI name for the specified bean.

Comment: Here is a similar question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-3-or-web-application-on-tomcat

Comment: Look at this link too its for Apache TomEE its application container from apache, while tomcat is a servlet container.

Comment: I am not using glass fish or OpenEJB. How can I able to find the JNDI name?

Comment: please read other comments as well there is a similar question and I have posted the link of that question in comment