# NullPointerException at @EJB Component

Tags: java, ejb

My code:

```
@Path("/actors")
public class MainController {

  @EJB
  private ActorDaoLocal actorDao;  

}

@Local
public interface ActorDaoLocal { 
  //some stuff here
}

@Stateless
public class ActorDao implements ActorDaoLocal {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em ; 
  //some stuff here 
}

@ManagedBean(name = "ActorBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ActorBean {

  @EJB
  private ActorDaoLocal usersDao;
}
```

When I am trying to use `actorDao` in `MainController` class, it is null. Why and how to fix it? I also tried to use `ActorBean` object, but it's also null.

Comment: How are you packaging your application?

Comment: @soong - It's not commont NullPointerException, but problem realated with EJB Injection.

Comment: @aribeiro - Maven-compiler-plugin, maven-war-plugin and Tomcat as server

Comment: Well Tomcat is not an application server. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-based-application-on-tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat isn't an application server but instead a servlet container. You should use [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) instead.

Comment: I've changed Tomcat to Glassfish and it's working. Thanks :)