# Web app works fine in Eclipse with Glassfish 4.1 but not when deployed to Tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, glassfish

I have followed instructions from http://zetcode.com/java/ejb/ to create a simple web app. It runs fine with eclipse, where it uses Glassfish server 4.1. To deploy to Tomcat, I simply copied the war file produced to the webapps folder of Tomcat 9. Tomecat 9 extracted the war file fine, and the HTML files work fine, but anything related to Java servlets fail, as shown below.

What could I be missing?
[image]

Comment: What is line 32 in Greet.java?

Comment: Tomcat does not have an EJB container!

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. As the hint states, you can find the full stack trace in the server logs.

Comment: Code is given in http://zetcode.com/java/ejb/. Anyway, line 32 in Greet.java is firstBean.setName(request.getParameter("name"));

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: That could very well be the reason. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Tomcat distribution doesn't support EJBs. Use Tomcat EE for that, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-based-application-on-tomcat#4304872).