# I can't import Java EE annotations in eclipse,such as @EJB and @Stateless, instead eclipse recommends me to create them

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, annotations, ide, ejb

I can't import Java EE annotations in eclipse,such as @EJB and @Stateless, instead eclipse recommends me to create them.

[Eclipse compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr80x.png)

Comment: Do you have the libraries with those classes on the project's Java Build Path? Typically they'd come from your targeted Server.

Comment: can you please share your `pom.xml`. You might miss the EJB API dependency

Comment: @nitind Do you mean a jar that should be in Tomcat's libraries?

Comment: @rieckpil There's not any pom.xml file as well

Comment: @IvanKarl Yes, but you can not use Tomcat itself for this. To have EJB support you need TomEE: http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html .

Answer (score 0):

Per se, you can't use the EJB specification with a plain Tomcat server. Tomcat is an  open-source implementation of the Java Servlet, JavaServer Pages, Java Expression Language and WebSocket specification.

The EJB (Enterprise JavaBeans) [specification](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/ejb/index.html) is part of Java EE (now called Jakarta EE) and requires a Java EE application server: e.g. TomEE, Payara, Glassfish, Open Liberty, WildFly, etc. Tomcat is not a Java EE application server as it is *just* a servlet-container.

If you still want to run your application in a Tomcat-like environment, have a look at the TomEE application server: [How to deploy EJB based application on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-based-application-on-tomcat).